# Give Docker containers IP's from host network with DHCP

Tags: docker, ip, portainer

I'm trying to give my Docker containers IPs from the host network, using DHCP.

To explain better, the Docker host has IP 192.168.1.5/24, and I want containers to automatically obtain IPs from the DHCP server in the 192.168.1.0/24 network (e.g. container1 gets IP 192.168.1.129).

I've tried with both macvlan and ipvlan, for example using this command

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
--subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
--gateway=192.168.1.1 \
-o parent=eth0 \
network-bridged
```

It seems that containers attached to that network gets an IP, but it's not inside the DHCP server range. I could manually set a range for containers with the `network` command, but I don't understand why containers also aren't able to publish ports.

Hope that somebody could help me

Comment: How do you assign specific IP addresses to other processes that aren't running in containers?  (Usually you don't worry about the container-internal IP addresses; from off-host you can't tell whether a given network listener is in a container or not.)